# Homestead user lost with all my DBs

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Second time in two weeks. I restart my vm just to notice that all my DB's are gone together with the homestead users.

Anyone has experienced this before?
Any idea on how I can recover my databases?

Comment: do you run any reprovisioning on your VM ? Just a restart (either vagrant reload or vagrant halt && vagrant up) should not delete any DB (unless its in memory DB of course)

Comment: It just happened again. Restarted my machine, went to put the VM up, and there, everything is running but the user homestead is gone for good.